# c# Regex replace with insert

Tags: c#, regex

I need to surround all '&' with '|' in a string but only if there is not already a '|' there
Eg. the following strings (--> expected result):

1. "Me&You" --> "Me|&|You"
2. "Me|&You" --> do not change
3. "Me&|You" --> do not change
4. "Me & You" --> "Me |&| You"

I figured out the selector (at least I think) which will catch example 1 and 4

```
[^|]&[^|]
```

But now im stuck creating the replace pattern.
I know I need something to copy the part before and after the '&' but can't get it working. The closest result was with

```
|&|
```

but this also removes the caracter before and after the '&'

NOTE: I can not use

```
s.Replace("&", "|&|").Replace("||&", "|&").Replace("&||", "&|");
```

as the string can already contain "||&" at the beginning and this will not create the expected results anyway.

Any alternative to regex is also welcome!

Comment: Do you need to replace & at the start/end of string? Are there consecutive &? If not, use capturing groups: `([^|])&([^|])` and replace with `$1|&|$2`.

Comment: If you need explanations, I could post my answer. Let me know if you need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<!\|)&(?!\|)
```

Comment: It might replace at the beginning and end of string.

Comment: Thank's it does what I need. Can you please explain how it works.

Comment: This page explains lookarounds very well: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 3):

This should work given your examples:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> tests = new List<string>();

    tests.Add("Me&You");
    tests.Add("Me|&You");
    tests.Add("Me&|You");
    tests.Add("Me & You");

    foreach (var item in tests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item,
                          Regex.Replace(item, @"(?<!\|)&(?!\|)", "|&|"));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression to search for `\|?&\|?` and replace with `|&|` would be a simple approach. This works at the start and end of lines, as well as within the lines.

The expression look for zero or one `|` characters before and also after the `&` and replaces all four variations (ie `&`, `|&`, `|&|` and `&|`) with the required text. The expression make no attempt to leave the existing `|` characters alone when they are correct.

Comment: But the question says "Me&|You" shouldn't be changed, this changes it to "Me|&|You"